# General proof of limit composition theorem on continuous function

Tags: limits

Let $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$, $a, b, c \in  \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, $a$ and $b$ be limit points of $A$ and $B$. Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g : B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I have to prove that if $b \in B$ and $g$ is cointinous in $b$ and

1. $\lim \limits_{x \to a}{f(x)} = b$
2. $\lim \limits_{y \to b}{g(y)} = c$

then $\lim \limits_{x \to a}{(g \circ f)(x)} = c$.
How to make a proof to as general theorem as above?

Comment: Hint: Show $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=c\iff$ for any $(x_n)\to a$, $f(x_n)\to c$

Comment: You should see the answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073047/72031 which shows that continuity of $g$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\varepsilon>0$.

By the second limit, $|g(y)-c|<\varepsilon$ for all $|y-b|<\delta$ for a certain $\delta>0$. By the first limit, $|f(x)-b|<\delta$ for all $|x-a|<\delta'$ for a certain $\delta'>0$. And thus, if $|x-a|<\delta'$, 
$$|f(x)-b|<\delta,$$
therefore 
$$|g(f(x))-c|<\varepsilon$$ if $|x-a|<\delta'$.

Comment: note that c could be $\infty$

Comment: Do you think continuity of $g$ at $b$ is needed in this question?

Comment: absolutely not ! The continuity is not necessary ! it would be important if $c=g(b)$, but not here.

Comment: Yes because $\lim \limits_{y \to b}{g(y)}$ don't need to be $g(b)$ otherwise.

Comment: but $\lim_{y\to b}g(y)\neq g(b)$ a priori.

Comment: If $g(y)$ is continous in $b$ then $\lim_{y\to b}g(y)= g(b)$ by definition.

Comment: right but your hypothesis is $\lim_{y\to b}g(y)=c$ not $g(b)$ !

Comment: Yes, but the assumption is nessesary.

Comment: no it's not necessary !

Comment: @idm The continuity is necessary. Your proof fails because the definition of function limit is when $\mathbf{0<}|y-b|<\delta$ we have $|g(y)-c|<\epsilon$. Counterexample can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069972/composition-of-limits