# Composition theorem for limits

Tags: calculus

Hello friends mathematician, i have a question, please help me, I need proof of this theorem.

## Theorem

Let *f* and *g* two real-valued functions, and $a$ is a cluster point of *Dom(f)* with 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) &= L\\
\end{align*}
and *g* continuous in *L*. Then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to a}  (g\circ f) (x)&= g(L)\\
\end{align*}
i.e.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to a} g(f(x))&=g(\lim_{x \to a} f(x))\\
\end{align*}

### Example

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(\cos(x))&=\sin(\lim_{x \to 0} \cos(x))=\ sin(1)=0.8414709848\
\end{align*}

Quote of the day:
"*In the 1950s, John Nash disrupted the balance between geometry and analysis when he discovered that the abstract geometric problem of isometric embedding could be solved by the fine “peeling” of partial differential equations*".
Cédric Patrice Thierry Villani
1973-present

Comment: You can get this proof from any elementary real analysis book. And probably it has been asked many times here. For example [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105555/general-proof-of-limit-composition-theorem-on-continuous-function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105555/general-proof-of-limit-composition-theorem-on-continuous-function)

Comment: Sorry. I enunciated the theorem bad, now is not the classic theorem of composition of functions.

Comment: $a$ is a cluster point of $f$?

Comment: yes, $a$ is a cluster point of $f$. It is an interesting theorem. Thank you.

Comment: @zhw cluster point = accumulation point

Comment: ... still... what is different than the link that I gave to you?

Comment: @Momo I know that. It's the "of $f$" I find strange. Probably should be "$a$ is cluster point of the domain of $f$"

Comment: I see now what you mean.