# Is my proof of "chain rule for limits" valid ? What can be other conditions for the "chain rule for limits"?

Tags: limits, proof-verification, proof-writing

Claim: if $f$ is a function and $g$ is a function and $a$ is the only solution to equation $$g(x)=g(a)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = g(a)$$ and $$\lim_{y \to g(a)} f(y) = L$$ then $$\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = L$$

Proof: $$\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = g(a)$$ so for every positive real number $\epsilon$ there exists positive real number $\delta$ such that from the fact $$0<|x-a|<\delta$$ follows $$|g(x)-g(a)|<\epsilon$$
Similiraly, $$\lim_{y\to g(a)} f(y) = L$$ so for every positive real number $\zeta$ there exists positive real number $\Delta$ such that from the fact $$0<|y-g(a)|<\zeta$$ follows $$|f(y)- L|<\Delta$$
Now we set y = g(x).
From the first limit we have that there exists some $\delta$ that from $$0<|x-a|<\delta$$ we get $$|g(x)-g(a)|<\zeta$$ because from the first limit we know that $\epsilon$ is any real number. But we know that $a$ is the only solution to the equation $$g(x)=g(a)$$ so from the fact that $$0<|x-a|<\delta$$ we can conclude that $$0<|g(x)-g(a)|<\zeta$$ Now we have that from the fact that $$0<|x-a|<\delta$$ we conclude that $$0<|g(x)-g(a)|<\zeta$$ and from that we conclude that $$|f(g(x))- L|<\Delta$$ so
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = L$$
Q.E.D.
Is this proof valid ? If so what are other sufficient conditions for such a chain rule ?

Comment: I believe most keyboards have a vertical bar on the backslash key used for LaTeX commands, it is usually shift + \ to get |, though abs(x) is still a perfectly good name for the function. Alternatively you could use \vert to get a vertical line though that's more work.

Comment: `\lvert` and `\rvert` are left and right delimiters, respectively.

Comment: Triatticus and Kevin thanks for advises.

Comment: @Triaticus thanks for advises

Comment: @Kevin thanks for advises

Comment: "$\lim_{g(x)\to g(a)} f(g(x)) = L$" what does that mean?

Comment: @zhw. It is a limit of a function $f$ with an input of $g(x)$ at point $g(a)$.

Comment: @zhw. What confuses you in that limit ? The fact that we have limit as $g(x)$ approaches $g(a)$ ? If it is so we can set $y=g(x)$ and the proof would be the same.

Comment: The limit notation involves variables and functions of variables. It has to be of the form $$\lim\limits_{\text{variables }\to\text{ values}} \text{ function of variables} $$ and not like $$\lim\limits_{\text{function }\to\text{ values}} \text{ function of variables}$$ So writing like $\lim_{g(x) \to g(a)} $ is non-standard.

Comment: Also there is limit of function at a point, not that limit of function "with some input" at some point. In symbols the notation $y\to g(a) $ and $g(x) \to g(a) $ are different. In first case $y$ takes all values in a neighborhood of $g(a) $ and in second case not all values in neighborhood of $g(a) $ are taken by $g(x) $.

Comment: For other sufficient conditions see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073047/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I could just say that "it is a limit of a function $f$ at a point g(a)". Or it would change something ?

Comment: Yes you should say that because that is the way to say it and just write $\lim_{x\to g(a)} f(x) =L$. You can also see my linked answer where I have given a result where the continuity of $g$ is not needed.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I saw it, but the problem is I am not familiar with  "neighborhoods".

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yeah, it is nonstandard, but I don't see some restrictions for that in the limit definition, or am I wrong ?

Comment: Neighborhood of a point $p$ is any open interval which contains $p$. Thus $(1,3)$ is a neighborhood of $2.95$. Further the notation and definition of limits is pretty standard and no textbook uses it in the manner you have used. It is better to use the standard notations to avoid ambiguity or otherwise you need to explain the non-standard notation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can't we just take standard definition of a limit and take $g(x)$ as an input of the function instead of $x$ and get what I wrote ? I mean, we have $$\lim_{x\to g(a)} f(x) = L$$ can't we just plug in $g(x)$ instead ?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the definition of neighborhood, now I will try to understand your variant of "chain rule".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74243/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and--).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh OK, let's continue the discussion in the chat.