# Prove if $\lim _{x\rightarrow0}(f(x))=L$ then $\lim _{x\rightarrow0}(f(x^3))=L$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Prove if $\lim _{x\rightarrow0}(f(x))=L$ then $\lim _{x\rightarrow0}(f(x^3))=L$

Can i just say that because $f(0)=f(0^3)$ it is true?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Is your function continuous? What have you tried? You need to provide more here. Do you need an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof or can you apply other arguments.

Comment: More general result holds true. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073047/72031 A proof can be provided without much effort using definition of limit.

Comment: This looks like a problem you have collected from / inspired by some source. According to recent discussions in Meta, we are looking forward to including sources for all applicable questions. Can you provide the source by editing the question?Refer-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $y=x^3$ since $y \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ (at least as fast) we have

$$\lim_{y \to 0}f(y)$$

Now, how do you get $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ given what you already know about $f(x)$'s limit.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function has been assumed to have a limit at $x=0$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta$ such that
$$
0<|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon.
$$
Now ask yourself, how close do we have to make $x^3$ from $x=0$ for $f(x^3)$ to be from $L$? It has already been given to us by the epsilon-delta definition of a limit: $x^3$ must be within $\delta$ of $0$, so by extension $x$ must be within $\sqrt[3]{\delta}$ of $0$. Therefore,
$$
0<|x|<\sqrt[3]{\delta}\implies|f(x^3)-L|<\epsilon.
$$
QED

Answer (score 0):

**Begining Hint:**

Suppose $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = L$ then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$
such that

$$0 < |x| < \delta \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$$

Now let $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta = \ ?$ Think what delta needs to be set to so that $|f(x^3) - L| < \epsilon$