# When is it possible to make a change of variables in the limit?

Tags: limits

When is it possible to make a change of variables in the limit?

For example $\lim_{x \to \infty}(\ln x/x)$, can I change $x=e^{y}$?

Then $\lim_{x \to \infty}(\ln x/x)= \lim_{y \to \infty}(y/e^{y})$?

How can I prove that the change of variables is valid?

Comment: See theorem mentioned at the end of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073047/72031 which can be adapted to deal with situation where we have $x\to\infty$. Your substitution is  valid

Comment: Such kind of theorems as mentioned in my previous comments are on par with algebra of limits and squeeze theorem and should be used regularly in evaluation of limits.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of the limit, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x) = L \iff \forall \epsilon>0, \exists N >0,|f(x)-L|<\epsilon,\forall x>N$.

As long as you can find a transformation $T(x)$ such that if $x>N$, then $T(x)>N$, you sill have that $|f(T(x))-L|<\epsilon$.

In your example, its obvious that if $x>N \implies e^x > N$.

Comment: Thank you!

And if $\lim_{x \to a}$ ?

Comment: The definition changes to $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0$ such that if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x) - L|< \epsilon$. Its a bit more tricky to find a $T(x)$ such that if $|x-a|< \delta$, then $|T(x)-a|< \delta$ but it's doable in certain case.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n > 0.$

$x_n \rightarrow \infty$, then

$y_n: =\log x_n \rightarrow \infty$(why?).

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \log (x_n)/x_n =$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n/(e^{y_n})=0$