# What's the difference between the two？

Tags: derivatives

## Question

Which of the following two can **define** the derivative $f'(a)$:

1)$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n \left[f\left(a+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(a)\right],n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

2)$$\lim_{x \to \infty}x\left[f\left(a+\frac{1}{x}\right)-f(a)\right],x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: Here, the fact $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}$ exists implies that $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}$ both exist and equal.

Comment: The second one is the definition of derivative as can be seen by using substitution $x=1/h$. The existence of first limit does not imply the existence of second limit, but existence of second limit implies the existence of first one so the first limit does not match the definition of derivative.

Comment: yes，I agree with you. But when can we make the subsitution?In another word, why we can not substitute $x$ for $1/n$?@ParamanandSingh

Comment: Refer to this answer for substitution rule of limits: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073047/72031 See the theorem mentioned at the end. It can be modified suitably for the case when variables tend to infinity.

Comment: The $1/n$ can't be substituted by $h$ because $1/n$ takes only a specific set of values namely rationals with numerator $1$ whereas $h$ takes all real values.

Comment: According to 2) the absolute value function would be differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
   0 & \text{If $x$ is rational.} \\
   1 & \text{If $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}$

Then $\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{n \to \infty} \\ n \in \mathbb{Z}}n \left[f\left(0+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(0)\right] = 0$

and

$\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{n \to \infty} \\ n \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb{Q}}n \left[f\left(0+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(0)\right] = \infty$.

Hence

$\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{n \to \infty} \\ n \in \mathbb R}n \left[f\left(0+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(0)\right]$ does not exist.