# Changing variables in limits (looking for the right theorem)

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Im looking for the right thorem that states under which conditions we can change the variables when calculating limits of 2 variables to polar coordinates variables.
All I found was way more complicates theorems with nore variables involving del operators like divergence and stuff.
I'll be glad if someone can point me to this theorem, preferable with proof.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a limit using change of variable- how come it works?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069642/finding-a-limit-using-change-of-variable-how-come-it-works)

Comment: No actually I mentioned I’m looking for generalization for 2 variables function

Comment: polar coordinates give the correct limit when you have a homogeneous expression, either a polynomial with all degrees equal, terms of the form $x^j y^{n-j}$ with fixed $n,$   or the quotient  of two such polynomials, while different degree on numerator  $n_N$ and denominator $n_D$ is allowed

Comment: The easiest example of failure is $ \frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}  $ as we get different limits along the curve $y=x^2$  from $y = -x^2 $