# Variable change theorem for limits, why is it important that $g(x)\neq b$ at some punctured neighborhood of $x=a$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

So the theorem is as follows.

> Suppose that $\,f(g(x))\,$ is defined in some punctured neighborhood
> of $\,x = a\,$, and that $\,g(x)\neq b\,$ there.
> If $\;\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=b\;$ and $\;\lim\limits_{t\to b}f(t)=L\;,\;$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(g(x))=L\,$.

I'm wondering what the meaning of $\,g(x)\neq b\,$ is. Can someone give an example of why this is important? I'm guessing it is possible to replace that part with that $\,g\,$ is continuous.

Comment: It is simply in general we don't assume that $f(t)$ is defined at $t=b$. It is unnecessary to define $\lim_{t\to b}f(t)$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073047/72031

Answer (score 2):

It is so important that $\;g(x)\neq b\;$ on some punctured neighborhood of $\,x=a\,$, because, if $\,g(x)=b\,$ on that punctured neighborhood, $\,\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(g(x))=f(b)\,$ that in general is different from $L$.
But if the function $\,f(t)\,$ were continuous at $\,t=b\,,\,$ it would not be necessary that $\;g(x)\neq b\;$ on some punctured neighborhood of $\,x=a\,.$

Comment: can u show an example why it is important that $g(x)\neq b$ on that punctured neighborhood.