# Question about limit substitution of non invertible functions

Tags: calculus, limits

I was working on limit substitutions, they make fair sense and are provable when we are dealing with invertible functions. But I was interested in substituting non-invertible functions like $\sin x$, even though the usefulness of that seems limited.

lets say there exist 2 functions $f(x)$ and $g(t)$ such that

$$t=s(x)$$
and
$$f(x) = g(t)$$
Then lets say there exists a limit

$$\lim_{x \to a} t=b$$
and we are trying to describe the approach of the following limit in terms of t.
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) $$
When trying to express the approach of x to a in terms of t, we need to show that x approaches a only when t approaches b. But since $s(x)$ is non invertible, then obviously $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to b} x$ does not exist. And we cannot express the $x \to a$ in terms of $t$. But since we know $f(x)=g(t)$, intuitively the following should be true because we are not involving $x$, there is no need to *extract* a value of $x$ from $t$.

$$\lim_{t \to b} g(t) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) $$

I know this is probably wrong, but can someone give a example where this does not work.

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073047/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I actually saw your answer before creating this question. But this was about straight substitution instead of something like $f(g(x))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $t$ as a function of $x$, and you have $g(t) = g(s(x)) = f(x)$. So $f=g\circ s$.

You have $$\lim_{x\to a}t = \lim_{x\to a}s(x) = b. $$

You are trying to find
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a}g(s(x)).$$
You are saying that "intuitively" we should have
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{t\to b}g(t) = \lim_{s(x)\to b}g(s(x)).$$

Consider
$$\begin{align*}
s(x) &=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1&\text{if }x\neq 0\\
0&\text{if }x=0.
\end{array}\right.\\
g(x) &= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
3&\text{if }x=0\\
4&\text{if }x=1\\
5&\text{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}$$
Then
$$g(s(x)) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
3 &\text{if }x=0\\
4 &\text{if }x\neq 0.
\end{array}\right.$$
Take $a = 0$ Then
$$\lim_{x\to 0}s(x) = 1,\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{x\to 0}g(s(x)) = 4.$$
So $b=1$.
However,
$$\lim_{t\to 1}g(t)=5.$$

If all the functions are continuous everywhere, however, then things work. If $s$ is continuous everywhere and $g$ is continuous everywhere, then
$$\lim_{x\to a}g(s(x)) = g\left(\lim_{x\to b}s(x)\right) = g(b) = \lim_{t\to b}g(t),$$
as desired.